# Handling Time value

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the below fields in UI

- Appointment Date  `04/13/2013`
- Start Time `13:00`
- End Time `14:30`

The current database design is

- AppointmentDate `SMALLDATETIME` Ex value `04-13-2013`
- Start Time `SMALLDATETIME` Ex value `04-13-2013 13:00`
- EndTime `SMALLDATETIME` Ex value `04-13-2013 14:30`

I designed a class for this model

```
public class Appointment
{
DateTime? AppointmentDate{get;set;}
DateTime? StartTime{get;set;}
DateTime? EndTime{get;set;}

}
```

I use ASP.Net MVC 4 and

```
 @Html.TextBox("", m.StartTime.ToString("HH:mm"))
```

Added jQuery validation plugin and i get validation message `14:30` is not a valid date.

What changes i can implement in *UI/DataBase/Validation* to handle time entry?

I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1):

Your start time and end time properties need to be decimals in the view model, as that is what you are passing back from the view on post.

Comment: I dont think `13:00` is a decimal value

Comment: 13.00 is, and solves the issue.  Better than parsing a string as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried explicitly setting the datatype of the columns:

```
public class Appointment
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? AppointmentDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }
}
```